# Are there any facilities to let us see what the employer sees when we apply for a job posting via SO?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I would like to view a sample of what an employer sees when I apply for a position.  I want to make sure the information is correct so I can decide wether to apply via SO or directly. Apparently, when I attach a resume, the system claims to submit a profile based on forms filled in SO. I normally don't bother filling them out which can be an issue.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Comment: Do users lose points, badges, etc. retroactively as a result of a SO deprecated SO product?  I understand this particular site doesn't award points, but I ask in general.

Comment: Truthfully, I think that's a rare enough situation where we'd want to handle it on a case-by-case basis. Something tickles my memory that this has come up before, but I think only once, if that. But I suspect we'd want to preserve it wherever possible, because rep is a core way we acknowledge long-term contribution.

Answer (score 7):

> If you don't upload a resume, we'll attach a PDF version of your CV for you. [Preview PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/apply/preview-pdf)

And the preview PDF looks like the one in the link.

According to the job application process, these are what will be sent:

- Full Name
- Phone Number
- Location
- Email
- The `Resume File` you upload OR an on-the-fly generated PDF from your SO CV
- and whatever you enter into the `Introduce yourself` box.

As to whether SO adds any other extra data along with the above, I don't know. I'm also curious to know if anything else other than the above are sent to the employer.

An exact copy of what was sent to the employer (not just `It was sent` message) in my inbox won't be a bad idea too.

Comment: Is this a question?  Or an answer?

Comment: @wallyk answer. It sounds like a question?

Comment: @Rexford Well, you seem not so sure about what the answer actually is: "I'm also curious to know if anything else other than the above are sent to the employer"

Comment: @Rakete1111 yep, that part is there because my answer is based on what the application process *says* will be sent to employer. However, I don't know *actually* what is sent. Just like th OP, I'll also like to know at least an exact copy of what the *employer actually sees*.

Comment: @Rexford I think then you could say something like: "The application process says that ... will be sent" or something. That way, if there is something else being sent, you're not at fault: you only stated what the application process said, not more, not less.

Comment: Geez, give the guy a break. He is reiterating the official answer, but like me, he wants to know what else is included..

Answer (score 4):

Rexford's answer is correct. The additional piece that's included in your application is a link to your Developer Story. [You can view this by clicking the "edit" link on the Apply modal.](https://goo.gl/mkgNtW)

There's currently no direct Apply > Preview my Developer Story link, however. Improving job applications is in our roadmap, and I'd expect your request to be a part of that project. This is a bit of usability debt that we'll need to address.

Since we don't have concrete plans yet, I've marked your question as status-review. Will update when I have more info. Thanks for pointing out the issue.